# PySpark Get row with max value from multiple columns grouped

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I would be happy for some help here :-)
I have the following dataframe:

```
Type | Number |    Date    | Value |
------------------------------------
   A |      1 | 2022-10-01 |     5 |
   A |      2 | 2022-10-01 |     8 |
   A |      3 | 2022-11-23 |     4 |
   B |      1 | 2022-02-02 |     1 |
   B |      2 | 2022-02-04 |     9 |
   B |      3 | 2022-02-04 |     3 |
   B |      4 | 2022-02-04 |     1 |
```

The result should be grouped by Type and Date and the Value should be the Value from the row where Number is the maximum (with the grouping condition):

```
Type | Number |    Date    | Value |
------------------------------------
   A |      2 | 2022-10-01 |     8 |
   A |      3 | 2022-11-23 |     4 |
   B |      1 | 2022-02-02 |     1 |
   B |      4 | 2022-02-04 |     1 |
```

I tried the following (in a few variations; also with groupBy()) but without success:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("Type", "Date")
df_result = (
    df.withColumn("MaxNumber", max("Number").over(w))
    .where(col("Number") == col("MaxNumber"))
    .drop("MaxNumber")
)
df_result.display()
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: when you say "without success", what does it mean ? you dot an error ? no filtering ? no output rows ? what is happening ? cause your code seems fine and should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine :

```py
df.withColumn("MaxNumber", F.max("Number").over(w)).where(
    F.col("Number") == F.col("MaxNumber")
).show()

+----+------+----------+-----+---------+
|Type|Number|      Date|Value|MaxNumber|
+----+------+----------+-----+---------+
|   A|     2|2022-10-01|    8|        2|
|   A|     3|2022-11-23|    4|        3|
|   B|     1|2022-02-02|    1|        1|
|   B|     4|2022-02-04|    1|        4|
+----+------+----------+-----+---------+
```

---

I would do it a bit differently, using [`row_number`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.row_number) instead :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("Type", "Date").orderBy(F.col("Number").desc())

df.withColumn("MaxNumber", F.row_number().over(w)).show()

+----+------+----------+-----+---------+
|Type|Number|      Date|Value|MaxNumber|
+----+------+----------+-----+---------+
|   A|     2|2022-10-01|    8|        1|  <--
|   A|     1|2022-10-01|    5|        2|
|   A|     3|2022-11-23|    4|        1|  <--
|   B|     1|2022-02-02|    1|        1|  <--
|   B|     4|2022-02-04|    1|        1|  <--
|   B|     3|2022-02-04|    3|        2|
|   B|     2|2022-02-04|    9|        3|
+----+------+----------+-----+---------+
```

Then you just filter `where("MaxNumber = 1")` :

```
df.withColumn("MaxNumber", F.row_number().over(w)).where("MaxNumber = 1").drop(
    "MaxNumber"
).show()

+----+------+----------+-----+
|Type|Number|      Date|Value|
+----+------+----------+-----+
|   A|     2|2022-10-01|    8|
|   A|     3|2022-11-23|    4|
|   B|     1|2022-02-02|    1|
|   B|     4|2022-02-04|    1|
+----+------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Somehow it did not work for me with my code. I always got the same data frame as I had as input. My guess is the `w = Window.partitionBy("Type", "Date")` did not work as it should. I got the same output as when I had this statement `w = Window.partitionBy("Type")`. But nevertheless your code worked for me.